# Efficient check of float division by zero for embedded application

Tags: c, performance, embedded, division, zero

For the embedded SW application on a microcontroller I have to write a some kind of customised division operator for float. The solution, I want to go with, is shortly described below.

In fact, I am not sure if this approach could be efficient enough in terms of execution time for the embedded application with high performance requirements.

Has anybody experience in diverse approaches to handle float division by zero, which can be efficient/optimised for embedded applications?

```
typedef union MyFloatType_
{
   unsigned long  Ulong;
   float          Float;
}MyFloatType;

float div_float(float a, float b)
{ 
   float numerator = a;
   MyFloatType denominator;
   denominator.Float= b;
   float result = 0.0f;

   if((denominator.Ulong & 0x7fffffffUL) != 0UL)
   {
      result = numerator / denominator.Float;

   } else 
   {
       /*handle devision by zero, for example:*/
       result = 0.0f;
   }
return result;
}
```

Comment: This code is invalid. Please post a compilable one.

Comment: Why not to check that the denominator is not *too close* to zero instead ?

Comment: Actually I did not mean to post a compilable code, it should be just an example of an approach. However now it should work .

Comment: I heard about this approach as well. However I am not sure if handling with integer within if() is a quite faster and precise then comparing with a float threshold, that has to be somehow arbitrary defined

Comment: If you are only interested in testing against the precise zero, but not any values extremely close to it, you can safely perform `==`, as zero has a precise representation in `float`. Otherwise your proposed approach won't help anyway.

Comment: I am not an expert in floating point optimizations. However, regardless of what you come up with, remember that you can't put a price on correctness. For starters, there's two different floating point zeros: `-0.0` and `+0.0`. Also, if a number is closer to zero than the machine's "epsilon", it might still end up as being zero. Good luck :-)

Comment: You have not said what you are trying to accomplish. Is this code intended to avoid a trap (change of program control) caused by division by zero, or is it intended to substitute a preferred result for the default result (an infinity when a non-zero is divided by zero and NaN otherwise), or something else? If it is merely trying to avoid an exception, can you just disable the trap for floating-point exceptions? If it is trying to substitute an alternate value, how is 1 better? There may be an alternative approach that is preferable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The goal of the code is to avoid ending up with NaN and propagating it to the calculation chain. The program control is strictly tracked in our application therefore exceptions are not intended at all. In case of division by zero, we replace the erroneous value by default one. It shall be detected the next the calculation chains and trigger a safety mode.

Comment: @NikosC. Yes the issue of two different zeros is treated also in the code, as the sign bit is masked away.

Comment: One of the purposes of NaN is to support detection of errors. How is substituting one and later detecting the problem better than not substituting one and later detecting the problem? Whatever method you are using to detect a problem (either because some calculated value is invalid or because some note was made that a zero divisor occurred) can be used just as well when no substitution is made.

Answer (score 2):

In most applications, there will be some value below which a floating-point number "might as well be" zero.  For example, consider something like:

```
float intensity(float dx, float dy)
{
  float result = 1/(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  if (result > 65535.0f) result = 65535.0f;
  return result;
}
```

If the divisor is less than 1/65535.0f, then in cases where the distance isn't exactly zero the function should return 65535.0f regardless of the actual value of the divisor, and such behavior would probably be useful even if it is zero.  Thus, the function could be rewritten as:

```
float intensity(float dx, float dy)
{
  float distSq = dx*dx + dy*dy;
  if (distSq <= (1.0f/65535.0f))
    return 65535.0;
  else
    return 1/distSq;
}
```

Note that the corner-case handling of this sort of code may be very slightly imperfect.  While not a problem for 65535.0f in particular, there may be cases where `distSq` is precisely equal to the reciprocal of the maximum value, but the reciprocal of that is less than the maximum value.  For example, if the maximum value was 46470.0f and `distSq` was 0.0000215238924f, the correct result would be 46459.9961f but the function would return 46470.0f.  Such issues are unlikely to pose problems in practice, but one should be aware of them.  Note that if the comparison had used less-than rather than less-than-or-equal, and the maximum had been 46590.0f, a `distSq` value of 0.0000214642932f would yield a result of 46589.0039, which exceeds the maximum.

Incidentally, on many systems, the cost of computing an approximate reciprocal of the divisor and multiplying by the dividend may be much cheaper than the cost of performing a floating-point division.  Such an approach may be useful in the many situations where its precision would be adequate.

Comment: If code was `if (distSq > (1.0f/65535.0f)) return 1/distSq; else return 65535.0;` then code would handle `dx` or `dy` as NaN nicely.

Comment: @chux: If one wants to handle the case of `NaN` inputs by yielding a maximum value, your approach would do so nicely.  As to whether it would be better to have NaN inputs yield a pegged value or NaN, that would depend upon whether such inputs could occur legitimately, or would indicate a need to fix problems that might otherwise go undetected.  Definitely a good consideration for which direction of comparison to use.

Comment: The approach is nice, thanks for the comments. I could go with a minimal threshold value, however generally one should compare the absolute value of the denominator. In my opinion, it does not make the code faster.

Answer (score 1):

It's not faster but potentially much slower.  It has to move the float to an integer register (possible by writing it into memory and reading it back) and then perform the integer operation.  Just perform `== 0.0f` and a floating point comparison is done instead and is the most efficient way.

If you want it to be "high performance" then try the following:

```
float div_float(float a, float b)
{ 
   b = b == 0.0f ? 1.0f : b;
   return a / b;
}
```

This can be optimized to few simple instructions without branching and is much faster overall as any branching kills performance.  This is used in graphics drivers where if the user is supplying garbage data that will eventually result in division by zero then the results are already invalid but throwing a floating point exception is not desired.

Comment: Appreciate you comment.  The ultimate way is to look up in assembly code and compare different approaches. Does the code work also with negative representation of zero?

Comment: Yes, in my experience the compiler has emitted the correct instructions to be branch-less and handle negative zero correctly.  In my experience you need to avoid branching statements as they will kill performance as the execution pipeline needs to be flushed and reloaded on a branch miss.  This takes longer then just performing the instructions like `fsel`.  Or you may be able to use branch hints.  But these types of details are architecture dependent.